# How do I make my footer display all the time?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listView in an xml and a footer i want to show in another xml.  The footer shows but only at the bottom of the list.  How do i get the footer to show all the time?

Here's my listview xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/borrowerName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="14sp"
     >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/borrowerGroupCode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/borrowerLoanAmount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
    android:layout_marginRight="5px" >
</CheckBox>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here's my footer xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button
android:id="@+id/disburse"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/submit"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the code i have put in my onCreate method :

```
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.loan_disbursement_footer, null);
getListView().addFooterView(footer);

setListAdapter(adapter);
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.disburse);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Help much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set the footer to

```
align_parent_bottom=true
```

then set your listview to

```
layout_above="footer"
```

Comment: that didn't work ... i used `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in the footer's xml and and my listView tag i used `android:layout_above="@+layout/loan_disbursement_footer"` (loan_disbursement_footer is the name of the footer's xml file)

Comment: I guess I was half using sudo code. I didn't think the syntax was correct